# PDO error al llamar al método prepare()

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Buenas,

Estoy aprendiendo `PHP` y practicando he creado dos clases. La finalidad es devolver la lista de usuarios de la tabla usuarios de la base de datos cursophp.

La clase `Connection` contiene lo siguiente (fichero: `conexion.php`):

```
<?php
   /**
    * Creamos una clase que contenga un conector a la base de base de datos
    */
   class Connection {

      // Creamos un atributo para guardar la conexion. En este atributo guardamos el conector a la base de datos MySQL
      protected $connectionDb;

      public function __construct() {

         // Hacemos un try catch para depurar errores
         try {

            // Creamos el constructor usando el atributo $connectionDb
            $this->connectionDb = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost; dbname=cursophp', 'root', '');

         } catch (Exception $e) {

            // Si hubiera algún error lo mostramos usando el método GetMessage
            echo "Error de conexión: " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>En la línea: " . $e->getLine();

         } finally {

            // Cerramos la conexión haya ténido éxito o no
            $this->connectionDb = null;
         }
      }
   }

   // Para comprobar la conexión instanciamos la clase Connection. No es necesario tenerla instanciada si no vamos a comprobarlo en el mismo fichero.
   // $conexion = new Connection;
?>
```

La clase `Usuarios` contiene lo siguiente (fichero: `usuarios.php`):

```
<?php
   // Incluimos la clase Conexion para poder crear una clase que la herede
   require("conexion.php");

   /**
    * Creamos una clase usuario que herede de la clase conexion (obtendrá como herencia el conector a la base de datos)
    */
   class Usuario extends Connection {

      // Atributos de la clase Usuario
      protected $idUsuario;
      protected $nombreUsuario;

      // Constructor de la clase
      function __construct() {

         #code...

      }

      // Método para devolver los usuarios de la tabla Usuarios
      public function GetAllUsers() {

         // Usamos try and catch para controlar los errores
         try {

            // Variable que contiene la sentencia SQL para MySQL
            $sql = 'SELECT * FROM usuarios';

            // Guardamos en la variable query la setencia sql usando la conexion de $connectionDb de la clase Connection con el método prepare de PDO
            $query = $this->connectionDb->prepare($sql);

            // Guardamos los registros en un array sin delimitar
            $query->execute(array());

            // Guardamos los resultaos en una variable llamada resultado y le aplicamos el método fetchAll
            $resultado = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            // Cerramos la query
            $query->closeCursor();

            // Y devolvemos los resultados para la función
            return $resultado;

            // Vaciamos el objeto connectionDb
            $this->connectionDb = null;

         } catch (Exception $e) {

            // Si hubiera algún error lo mostramos usando el método GetMessage
            echo "Error: " . $e->GetMessage() . "<br>línea: " . $e->getLine();

         }

      }

   }

?>
```

Y por último tengo un tercer fichero llamado `verclientes.php` para devolver la lista de usuarios.

En la tabla de prueba tengo dos usuarios.

```
<?php
   // Incluimos el fichero usuarios.php para tener la clase Usuario disponible
   require("usuarios.php");

   // Creamos un objeto nuevo de usuarios
   $usuarios = new Usuario();

   // Creamos un array donde se guardará los resultados de la lista de usuarios
   $arrayUsuarios = $usuarios->GetAllUsers();

   foreach ($arrayUsuarios as $elemento) {
      echo "<table><tr><td>";
      echo $elemento['nameuser'] . "</td></td></tr></table>";
      echo "<br>";
   }
?>
```

El error me lo da en el fichero `usuarios.php` en la línea donde se usa el método `prepare()`.

Cómo no sé exactamente donde está el error he puesto los tres ficheros, si consideráis que está mal incluir excesiva información avisadme y elimino lo que sobre.

La línea del error es esta:

```
$query = $this->connectionDb->prepare($sql);
```

Y el error es este:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\wamp64\www\test\php\usuarios.php on line 31

He revisado varias veces la línea pero no sé dónde está el error. ¿Podéis ayudarme por favor?

Comment: ¿Puedes enseñar el constructor de la clase Usuarios? Creo que tu problema es que no inicializas el objeto PDO.

Comment: @Error404 está puesto todo lo que hay en la clase Usuario.. ¿lo que me falta es el constructor?

Comment: Probé a ponerle al constructor un parent::__construct(); pero seguía dando el mismo error.

Comment: Realmente cuando haces $this haces referencia al objeto actual, por lo tanto, ahora estás haciendo referencia a un objeto que no existe (que no has inicializado).

Comment: ¿Y cómo lo inicializo? Porque en la clase tengo el __construct...

Comment: Me refiero el problema es que al hacer $this->connectionDb realmente lo que no está inicalizado es la conexión

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Problemas que hay en el código que compartes y que causan el error:

1. En la clase `Usuario` nunca se llama al constructor del padre (el *super*). Deberías hacer algo como esto:

   ```
   parent::__construct();
   ```

   de lo contrario nunca se llamará al constructor del padre y nunca se creará la conexión.
2. Incluso si llamas al constructor del padre, recibirás el error. Eso ocurre porque en la clase `Connection` se crea la conexión a la base de datos en un `try-catch`... e inmediatamente se cierra en el `finally`:

   ```
   } finally {
       // Cerramos la conexión haya ténido éxito o no
       $this->connectionDb = null;
   }
   ```

   Ahí cierras la conexión y ya no puede usarse más. Por eso cuando intentas hacer un `prepare` recibes el error que recibes, porque en ese momento, la conexión que intentas utilizar es `null`.

   Comenta o borra esa línea y ese problema desaparecerá (nota que al final de la función `GetAllUsers()` intentas cerrar la conexión, lo cual te podría crear problemas más adelante... pero como la cierras después de un `return`, ese código es inaccesible y nunca se ejecutará)

Comment: Efectivamente era eso. Pensaba que con el finally podía cerrar la conexión, por temas de seguridad. Ya veo que no es así. Muchas gracias Alvaro!

Comment: No me había dado cuenta del `finally`. Bien visto Alvaro :)